# Hive SQL using TEZ as execution engine not giving result on empty partition

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

Hive SQL's on empty partitions giving no result instead of 0 rows or actual value. For example -

--Create external Table

1. `Create external table test_tbl ( name string) partitioned by ( company string, processdate string) stored as orc location '/my/some/random/location';`

– Add partion

2. `Alter table test_tbl add partition ( company='aquaifer', processdate='20220101');`

– Execute following SQL's which returns no records.

3. `select max( company ) , processdate  from test_tbl  group by processdate  ;`
4. `select max(processdate ) from test_tbl  ;`

Same SQL (#3 & #4 above) , when execute with SPARK, returns  '0' count and  '20220101' respectively.

Why is this behavior difference ? How can we have a table partition with 0 rows in Hive?

Comment: It can be due to this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TEZ-1135 Check your Tez version the same as one of affected versions in Jira

Comment: We are on Tez 0.9.1.3.1.5.0-152. The bug mentioned was fixed in 0.5.0